# Can the equation $\frac{1}{3}ML^2 $ be used to calculate the moment of inertia in a non-uniform rod?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am wondering whether the moment of inertia about a pivot at one of its ends of a non-uniform rod can be calculated using the following equation:
$$\frac{1}{3}ML^2$$

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot use this formula. Imagine that all mass of the rod is concentrated at one end, the the moment of inertia will be either $0$ or $M L^2$.  The correct formula for the moment of inertia in your case is
\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^L dx \rho(x) x^2,
\end{equation}
where $\rho(x)$ is the linear mass density of the rod. For a uniform rod $\rho(x)=\frac{M}{L}$, and then integration leads to $I = \frac{1}{3}ML^2$.

Comment: \begin{equation}
\rho(x)= \left \{
\begin{array}{lll}
\rho_1, x\in (0,6)~\cup~(7,10), \\
\rho_2, x\in (6,7).
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Comment: @nwolijin Can I interpret that as taking three segments and finding their moment of inertia about their center of mass and then using the parallel axis theorem to a point about which the whole body rotates about?

Comment: @DuckTales  You can just do piecewise integration over the three segments. The integral from 0 to 10 is the sum of the integrals from 0 to 6, 6 to 7, and 7 to 10. The axis of rotation is the same for each segment, not simply parallel.

Comment: @JustJohan you can do that

Answer (score 1):

No. When deriving this equation from the moment of inertia definition, the density $\rho$ is assumed to be uniform. If the density is not uniform, the $\dfrac{1}{3}ML^2$ equation does not hold.

You would have to use $$I = \int r^2 dm$$ equation to find the moment of inertia of your non uniformly dense rod.

EDIT: as noted by user @Andrew Steane, for some 'special' density distributions it would hold.

But as a general rule, no (except in certain cases).

Comment: (well of course for some special density distributions it would hold :))

Comment: that is true :P